# How to get int value from tf.size() without using session

Tags: tensorflow

```
label_one = [0,1,1,0,0,0,0]
tf.size(label_one) # returns a tensor
```

How to get the value from the tensor without using session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming it's a tensor's length you want to derive using TensorFlow, following should work.

```
label_one = tf.constant([0,1,1,0,0,0,0])
print(label_one.shape[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
label_one = tf.constant([0,1,1,0,0,0,0])
tf.size(label_one).numpy()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).